# A small problem with originating vectors from one point

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a simple picture - three vectors, originating from the (0, 0) point.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,titlepage,makeidx]{article}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, decorations.pathreplacing, calc, matrix, shapes, arrows, decorations, decorations.text, fit}

\newcommand{\dimlabel}
    {%
        \begin{tikzpicture}%
            \draw[-latex', line width = 1pt] (0, 0) -- (0, 1);%
            \draw[-latex', line width = 1pt] (0, 0) -- (1, 0);%
            \draw[-latex', line width = 1pt] (0, 0) -- (1, 1);%
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (S){\dimlabel};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I use MikTeX 2.9 under Windows with pdfLaTeX.
The problem is that, if you run this simple example, and then open file in, say, Adobe Reader, and zoom the page really close, like 1200%, you will see that vectors, which form right angle have small gap in the point of origin. 
The picture explains my point better. How can I avoid this effect? [image: Tikz problem]

Comment: You can add `line cap=rect` to the orthogonal paths.

Comment: @Jake perhaps you should turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 6):

PSTricks can also be used to explain your problem. You need to change the `linecap` (PSTricks' term) or `line cap` (TikZ's term) from `0` (default) to `1`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks,multido}
\psset{linewidth=2pt,arrows=->}
\begin{document}
\multido{\i=0+1}{3}{%
\begin{pspicture}(1,1.5)
    \psset{linecap=\i}
    \psline(0,1)
    \psline(1,1)
    \psline(1,0)
    \rput(0.5,1.25){\tiny linecap=\i}
\end{pspicture}\quad}
\end{document}
```